# Events not rendering in FullCalendar agendaWeek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to render events in the "agendaWeek" view, with no luck. I'm declaring FullCalendar in my document.ready like so:

```
$("#calview").fullCalendar({
    theme: false,
    header: false,
    weekends: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: 8,
    maxTime: 20,
    height: 800,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    editable: false,
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'dddd',
        week: 'dddd',
        day: 'dddd'
    },
    events: MyEvents
});
```

And no matter what I give the "events" option, be it an array, a callback function, or simply a single Event object, it does not render. However, if I comment out the "defaultView" option and let it default to a month view, my events render.

I tried following suggestions to set "allDay" to false, or the empty string, etc., all to no avail.

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works for me, if i remove the "allDaySlot" parameter. Did you give that a try?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that and all it did was show the all day row at the top of the calendar. If I set the event's "allDay" field to "true", or removed it, that event would show up in that all day row, but would be invisible otherwise.

Comment: EDIT: Oh you know what, I was being really stupid and all my events were at 4:30am, but my agenda view was only showing 8am to 8pm. Thanks for your reply though!